# Server got blank with error: -bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: linux, php, load-balancing

My Vps is not executing any command. Server load is high and memeory usage is 100% due to which this error occured

**-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory**.

I just want to what is this process PHP and why user frie is getting so many requests to execute this. due to which i am getting short of memeory.
Kindly help me what to do in this situation.

Output of top

```
top - 08:48:07 up  3:40,  2 users,  load average: 57.30, 35.14, 26.40
Tasks: 204 total,  64 running, 126 sleeping,   0 stopped,  14 zombie
Cpu(s): 83.7%us, 15.3%sy,  0.0%ni,  1.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,0.0%st
Mem:   1572864k total,  1570704k used,     2160k free,        0k buffers
Swap:  2097152k total,   812544k used,  1284608k free,     6588k cached

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
5056 frie      20   0  166m  32m 6028 R  2.0  2.1   0:00.55 php
5062 frie      20   0  164m  31m 5996 R  2.0  2.1   0:00.50 php
5077 frie      20   0  157m  31m 5880 R  2.0  2.0   0:00.38 php
5091 frie      20   0  151m  26m 5840 R  2.0  1.7   0:00.28 php
5105 frie      20   0  138m  19m 5608 R  2.0  1.2   0:00.12 php
4942 demoin    20   0  210m  15m 5564 R  1.7  1.0   0:00.80 php
5020 frie      20   0  174m  31m 6260 R  1.7  2.1   0:00.97 php
5022 frie      20   0  174m  44m 6132 R  1.7  2.9   0:01.01 php
5031 frie      20   0  175m  30m 6168 R  1.7  2.0   0:00.92 php
5041 frie      20   0  169m  33m 6208 R  1.7  2.2   0:00.72 php
5043 frie      20   0  168m  41m 6112 R  1.7  2.7   0:00.68 php
5044 frie      20   0  166m  41m 6204 R  1.7  2.7   0:00.69 php
5045 frie      20   0  168m  41m 6212 R  1.7  2.7   0:00.69 php
5046 frie      20   0  168m  40m 6144 R  1.7  2.6   0:00.67 php
5047 frie      20   0  168m  37m 6164 R  1.7  2.4   0:00.64 php
```

Screen-Shot

[image]

Comment: Most VPS systems have a web based admin GUI through which you can restart the VPS. Do that first so you can actually do some commands again and investigate. To then prevent this, you can consider monit, it's a monitoring tool through which you can say "if any process consumes more than X% of memory, restart it" for example.

Comment: Basic things i have done, i have suspended this user from VPS and now everything is normal. I just wanted to know what was PHP which was executing every second how this all happened?

Comment: Do you have access log enabled? http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Finding_Causes_of_Heavy_Usage You can query that log and see which file is hit most, that's probably the one you need to investigate.

Comment: @thanks for sharing above post, but there are no logs for this in file **access_logs**, logs are generating in file **suphp_log**

Comment: Download that log, or just navigate to its folder, and run awk '{print $7}' suphp_log|cut -d? -f1|sort|uniq -c|sort -nk1|tail -n10 to generate a list of files or directories on your site being called the most.

Comment: output:        6 Directory
                   2039 File
                   535137 Executing

Answer (score 3):

This should be a comment, but its a bit long.

This system is not coping with the demand being placed on it. However you've not provided nearly enough information to diagnose what is going on let alone fix the problem. But the information needed is orders of magnitude greater than would be considered appropriate for a post here.

But you did ask a specific question

> I just want to what is this process PHP and why user frie is getting so many requests to execute this

There's nothing in the information you've provided to prove that this is the cause of the problems you are experiencing. Certainly the system does not appear to be [configured to manage the demand](http://lampe2e.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/accurate-capacity-planning-with-apache.html).

That the PHP processes are running as user 'frie' gives me some cause for concern. It rather implies that this machine might be configured to use suPHP or similar - this simply does not scale.

That the processes are executing for up to 1 second suggests that they are either processing huge amounts of data, are very innefficiently written and/or opcode caching is not working.

Depending on what the "normal" state of the system is, and exactly how the system has been configured, it should be possible to determine what the traffic causing the problem is from the access logs. Amending the logs to include the response time, and ideally the TTFB will help.

Some webservers can expose a current status including the urls being processed at any time (extended server status for Apache) but you didn't say what webserver is involved here, or even if the machine has a webserver.

Comment: Post was useful i up-voted for the effort but didn't get the answer, may you please guide what details should i provide you with to have this diagnosed..

Comment: You can also consider profilers like blackfire.io and New Relic to ascertain which PHP scripts are doing all this heavy lifting.